# Print only the columns which are selected using checkbox in a ASP.Net Gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in which i want to place a checkbox for each column of gridview and also i need to print only those columns which are checked.How can i do this?
Right now i am simply binding the Gridview from Code behind.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grd1" CssClass="serh-grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                        ShowFooter="false" TabIndex="1" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
                                        GridLines="Vertical" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None"
                                        BorderWidth="1px" >                                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#000000" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="true" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="grid-sltrow" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BorderStyle="Solid"
                                            BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```